# #c strcmp() isn't working as it should

Tags: strcmp

I want to compare between two char* so i do it with strcmp,
look, in debugging mode, both char* in strcmp gets the same value and still it
wont return 0, and it jumps over the if() condition instead of entering it:

here pic from the debugger:
http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/5218/111fi.jpg

```
Company FindCompany(CompanyL pcompanyList, int companyIdentityDigit) 
{
    Company companyFound;
    char *psearchWord;
    psearchWord = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));

    switch(companyIdentityDigit) {
        case 0: 
            strcpy(psearchWord , "Pelephone");
            break;
        case 2: 
            strcpy(psearchWord , "Cellcom");
            break;
        case 4: 
            strcpy(psearchWord , "Orange");
            break;
    }

    while(pcompanyList->next != NULL)   {
        if(strcmp(pcompanyList->thisCompany->pcompany , psearchWord) == 0)  {
            free(psearchWord);
            return pcompanyList->thisCompany;
        }
        pcompanyList = pcompanyList->next;
    }
    free(psearchWord);
    return NULL;
}
```

why is it??

Comment: What values are you calling it with.

Comment: Are the strings definitely both ASCII?  Are you sure the bytes after the m's in Cellcom are both nulls?

Comment: right james...i'll fix it, but it isn't the problem

Comment: jtdubs - maybe not, but i added pic of debugging with the values of those chars*...

Comment: Have you tried to print out both pcompany and psearchWord, and print out the byte code version of each letter to ensure that they are identical.  Strcmp has been around a long time, I doubt there is some bug in this code.

Comment: and james..no, after re checking it never do twice free(), after the first one i've got return so it won't get to the other one...and what are byte code version?

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple for loop to print out the characters in pcompanyList->thisCompany->pcompany one at a time:

```
for (int x = 0; x < strlen(pcompanyList->thisCompany->pcompany); x++)
    printf("%c ", pcompanyList->thisCompany->pcompany[x]);
```

You can do this or check the length of each string to make sure there aren't hidden characters that aren't showing up in the debugger when you check the strings.