# Comparing chars[] does not work

Tags: c, strcmp

I have problem with strcmp function (same question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300325/c-strcmp-isnt-working-as-it-should), but there aren't good answers). If I compare 2 same strings, but one string is from structure, this string is wrongly "translated" to assembly code. Every char[] from structure are random 3 characters.
[Picture of strcmp.asm](http://s17.postimg.org/3rali3ga7/V_st_i_ek.png)

```
#define CONS 60

typedef struct LinkCity{
    char city[CONS];           // i get this char[] from file by using fgets()
    struct LinkCity* next;
} tLinkCity;
/***************************************/
    typedef struct {
        int NumberOfCity;
        tLinkCity* Link;
        double** distances;
    } tDatabaze;
/***************************************/
int GetIndexOfCity(tDatabaze* db, char * city){

    printf("%s %s", db->Link->city, city); //   > Barcelona\n Barcelona (yes, here is a newline)
    str = strcmp(db->Link->city, city);    //   str = 1  (=it should be 0)
}
```

Comment: When you retrieved the string using `fgets()`, did you also remember to *remove* the newline from the end? And what is `tSeznamMest` and where is `db->Link` even allocated? Post a *real* example that reproduces the problem plz.

Comment: What does this have to do with assembly?

Comment: sorry for tSeznamMest, edited...

Comment: There may be non-printing characters in the strings. What does `strlen()` say for the two strings?

Comment: Please post the code where you write to your two character arrays.

Comment: Oli: isn't .asm assembly file? :)

Comment: @Pivoman: Sure, but what does this have to do with your code?  You should just be able to describe the symptoms from a C point-of-view...

Comment: If your question is about your own asm function, you should post that, not the C code.

Comment: isn't asm function, this picture is just from debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing the newline from the end of the string before comparing , here's a simple function to does that :

```
void removeNLine(char* string)
{
        int i ;
        for(i = strlen(string) ; i > 0 ; i--)
               if(string[i] == '\n')
                     string[i] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken function `fgets` reads also the new line character into the array. So I think the reason of that two arrays are not equal each other is that one that was read by using `fgets` contains the new line character.

Comment: The newline would be printed by `printf()`, wouldn't it?

Comment: I know, but I try to copy (using strcpy()) and this doesn't work too.

Comment: @Barma, Yes, it can help to determine whether there is indeed a new line character.

Comment: @Pivoman It is not clear what you are trying to copy and what is the problem with that.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Then why isn't he seeing the newline in his printf?

Comment: @Barma I do not know whether he is seeing it or not.:)

Comment: I tried Strncpy (with Barcelona - 9 chars) to orher char[] too, but this didn't help. I just need to know how to compare this chars[]

Comment: @Pivoman Include a simple test code. char *p = db->Link->city, *q = city; while ( *p && *q )  printf("%u %u\n", ( int )*p++, ( int )*q++); if ( *p != *q ) puts( "The string have different lengths!" );